# How to update column value after particular time interval

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to update a particular column value from Yes to NO after particular time interval mentioned in the same table.

Table Structure

```
`v_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`society_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`voting_for` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`active` enum('Yes','No') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Yes',
`voters` varchar(10000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_by` int(11) NOT NULL
`active_till` date NOT NULL
```

How can i change Active column value from Yes to No once active_till period expires. i'm doing this in Codeigniter.

Comment: see if you can create an event in mysql and update the Active column as a scheduled job. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 1):

as my reputation is below 50, so i am not allowed to comment,

you can set a cron for that job, and run the cron after every 1 minute interval or 5 minutes and update the active column to YES or NO by comparing your active_till column with todays date or your choice.

hope this will give you a good idea for setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be much easier for you to use MySql Events

it will be faster to run as no need for PHP to run.

Use PHPMyAdmin, go to your database -> Events -> Add Event and from there

That will make your query something like :

UPDATE #__active_run SET active=NO

Set the Interval  of time it should be update.